# Concatenar palabras dentro de formato de hora

Tags: vb.net, .net

Estoy utilizando el siguiente método para establecer un formato de día y hora personalizado en VB.NET . Sin embargo, quiero que el día y la hora se despliegue tal como se ve en Windows cuando colocas el cursor encima de la hora "Ej: 25 de Julio de 2017"):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd  de MMMM yyyy HH:mm")
```

¿Cómo lo podría hacer sin fallar en el intento? Si lo dejo así como está, el "de" se transforma en 25e, lo cual no es correcto.

Saludos y gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplemente tienes que escapar el texto con comillas simples `'`:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd  'de' MMMM yyyy HH:mm")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfecto

Comment: @KPavezC cuando te sea posible, recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada